# What is the best landscaping material next to my foundation?

Tags: foundation

I have 1/2" river rock against the perimeter of my foundation...

[image]

One contractor told me this was good to keep ticks and ants away from my basement.

One contractor told me this pools water and causes basement moisture.

Another contractor told me to grade mulch against the foundation for water run-off.

I live in the Northeast.

Is river rock a good perimeter material?

Comment: Ticks and ants don't give a fig. Water pooling or not pooling depends on the grading and material of the **substrate** of the stone layer or mulch (or other material.) So they are all three wrong. This is an opinon based question ("what is the best") and will likely be closed unless/until you [edit] it so as not to be opinion based. If you have basement moisture problems, the first question this picture raises is "where does that downspout actually go?" If you don't have basement moisture problems, that's a red herring.

Comment: What do you mean by "best" ? Expense and time to install will both depend on where you're located, and are both off-topic here. "Quality of repair" is opinion, also off-topic. This isn't a disucssion forum. Read the [Help file](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how the site works.

Comment: Totally depends on where the water goes underground.  Effectively a body of rocks replacing dirt is a freeway for water movement, or a "drain".  But a drain without an outlet isn't a drain at all.

Answer (score 1):

3/4 crush is the general code approved material for subslab drainage layer.  This minimizes the rock to rock wicking potential and keeps water from migrating upwards and allows drainage.

On the exterior next to your house it depends.  In your case I can see that you have 4" pvc rain drains and the foundation looks modern so I'll assume you have perforated perimeter drains around the footings of your house.  I don't see any dimple board or evidence of damp proofing.  I'll assume you have damp proofing applied to the exterior of the concrete walls.  What you don't want is your foundation walls serving as a dam with a large hydrostatic load and you also don't want water sitting against the damp proofing looking for a way to wick into the concrete.  Any kind of drainage rock is going to help prevent water from sitting against the foundation wall.

The ideal thing is landscape fabric to prevent fines from getting into the drainage rock and drainage rock going all the way down to your perimeter drains.  This also discourages plants from putting roots down into your perimeter drain.

The 1/2" river rock is a good choice as it looks nice and provides the drainage.